Why does my SFML template program contains basic include errors but still runs?
So I successfully set up an SFML project and thought I would make a template of it so I don't have to go through those steps again. However, when I made a new test program based on that template it is littered with the usual include errors like it can't find the libraries. However it runs successfully? I can even make changes to the code and it successfully runs. (It just shows a circle on the screen, and I can modify the circle and change it's color for example)
I have never experienced this before and could not find anything similar to this. Does anyone know why this might be?
Regards
Here is my brief test program (with the errors):

List of include related errors:

It builds successfully:

UPDATE: When I switch from debug to release the errors go away.
